# Select2 dropdown with dynamic name and image in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, jquery-select2

I am working on yii2.

I have form with many fields.

I have one field that which has name and image.

I want to display that with select2 dropdown with name and image. Name is coming but how to display image in that dropdown.

**Yii view file code :**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
          <?= $form->field($model,'db_fieldname')->dropDownList(['0'=>'Select category']
          + ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(),'id','name'),
          ['multiple'=>'multiple']) ?>
       </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**I have wrote JS :**
At the end of my view file

```
<?php
    $this->registerJs('$("select").select2( templateResult: format);');
 ?>
```

**Now according to above code please guide me how to display image in dropdown.**

Answer (score 0):

Take look Here...
Might be helpful to you.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating

Comment: thanks.... i have read but i have dynamic data. What should i write in place of state ? from given example

Comment: you may create a function in your model and can use that funstion in dropdown

Comment: can you give example please ?

Comment: ok m getting data. but i want to print image name in place for src but i am getting id and text only in select2